# Which is the best way to release thread that uses BlockingCollection?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a class that uses BlockingCollection like this:

```
public class Logger : IDisposable
    {
        private BlockingCollection<LogMessage> _messages = null;
        private Thread _worker = null;
        private bool _started = false;

        public void Start() 
        {
            if (_started) return;
            //Some logic to open log file
            OpenLogFile();      
            _messages = new BlockingCollection<LogMessage>();  //int.MaxValue is the default upper-bound
            _worker = new Thread(Work) { IsBackground = true };
            _worker.Start();
            _started = true;
        }

        public void Stop()
        {   
            if (!_started) return;

            // prohibit adding new messages to the queue, 
            // and cause TryTake to return false when the queue becomes empty.
            _messages.CompleteAdding();

            // Wait for the consumer's thread to finish.
            _worker.Join();  

            //Dispose managed resources
            _worker.Dispose();
            _messages.Dispose();

            //Some logic to close log file
            CloseLogFile(); 

            _started = false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implements IDiposable 
        /// In this case, it is simply an alias for Stop()
        /// </summary>
        void IDisposable.Dispose() 
        {
            Stop();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is message consumer thread
        /// </summary>
        private void Work()
        {
            LogMessage message;
            //Try to get data from queue
            while(_messages.TryTake(out message, Timeout.Infinite))
                WriteLogMessage(message); //... some simple logic to write 'message'
        }
    }
```

I create a new instance of the Logger class, call its Start() method. Then, if I forget to call the Dispose method when the instance is no longer referenced, then the Worker Thread will never end. That's a kind of memory leak. Am I right? and how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to keep only a weak reference to the `BlockingCollection` in your worker thread and do not reference an object that is referencing the `BlockingCollection`. I made a static method to ensure that we don't reference the Logger instance `this`.

This way the collection can be finalized/collected when it is no longer referenced. I'm not sure it'll work, you have to try, It depends on whether TryTake keeps the collection alive or not. It may not work in debug as the GC behave differently, so try it in release without debugger attached.

```
public class Logger : IDisposable
{
    private BlockingCollection<LogMessage> _messages = null;
    private Thread _worker = null;
    private bool _started = false;

    public void Start() 
    {
        if (_started) return;
        //Some logic to open log file
        OpenLogFile();      
        _messages = new BlockingCollection<LogMessage>();  //int.MaxValue is the default upper-bound
        _worker = new Thread(Work) { IsBackground = true };
        _worker.Start(new WeakReference<BlockingCollection<LogMessage>>(_messages));
        _started = true;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {   
        if (!_started) return;

        // prohibit adding new messages to the queue, 
        // and cause TryTake to return false when the queue becomes empty.
        _messages.CompleteAdding();

        // Wait for the consumer's thread to finish.
        _worker.Join();  

        //Dispose managed resources
        _worker.Dispose();
        _messages.Dispose();

        //Some logic to close log file
        CloseLogFile(); 

        _started = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Implements IDiposable 
    /// In this case, it is simply an alias for Stop()
    /// </summary>
    void IDisposable.Dispose() 
    {
        Stop();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is message consumer thread
    /// </summary>
    private static void Work(object state)
    {
        LogMessage message;
        //Try to get data from queue
        do
        {
            BlockingCollection<LogMessage> messages;
            if (((WeakReference<BlockingCollection<LogMessage>>)state).TryGetTarget(out messages)
                && messages.TryTake(out message, Timeout.Infinite))
            {
                WriteLogMessage(message); //... some simple logic to write 'message'
                continue;
            }
        } while (false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think It doesn't work, because messages.TryTake() will block forever if the CompleteAdding() method of BlockingCollection is not called.
I can use a specific timeout for TryTake(), but i will make the loop spin over and over

Comment: I think that when the BlockingCollection is finalized, it'll 'unblock' TryTake but I don't know if it can really happen while you are calling TryTake... You should try it.